# Why doesn't the view show every node?

Tags: views, search

I have created a view as a page that I want to only show my blog posts. I filter the `Content: Has taxonomy term (= blog)` to limit to my blog posts. Now I want to add a search box that can search the title and body. I've tried using `Search: Search Terms` and `Global: Combine fields filter`, but neither seems to work properly. They don't bring up any posts that match the search, even if the text is in the title, body, or the exact name of a linked taxonomy.

How can I make a search box for my view that will search the title and body?

Comment: Have you indexed those nodes?

Comment: Yes. They were all indexed, as made clear by them showing up when I did a search in a search form. The issue was that `Global: Combine fields filter` only searches fields that are manually set.

Answer (score 0):

I have just learned that in order to use `Global: Combine fields filter`, you must set "Show" (under the "Format" section) to "Fields". My issue was I had it set to "Content" and couldn't select the fields in the settings for the filter.